# could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Yesterday wasn't this error. I didn't make any changes in my application.
Just went to sleep and now I get this.

Error:

```
home/dartnyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/
postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize': could not connect to server:
No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  imeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: shop_development
  pool: 5
  username: dartnyan
  password: kurt1245
test:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: shop_test
 pool: 5
 username: dartnyan
 password: kurt1245
```

Comment: I wouldn't advice leaving your username and password in the open web like that.

Comment: @luissimo I don't leave any links to my application, but ok, I won't leave these fields next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reinstalled PostgreSQL and now it works.

Comment: can be done by rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid

Answer (score 34):

I found that typing the following into terminal helps:

```
$ cd /usr/local/var/postgres/

$ rm postmaster.pid
```

I found this over at http://alumni.lewagon.org/questions/60

It also describes what might be happening.  The file may get corrupt if Postgresql was not closed 'gracefully'. Example would be if your battery on your laptop were to die.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16853088)

Comment: @MikeT Thank you for the feedback.  I hope my edits are better.

Comment: I have done this via finding what port PG is on, killing the PID (But you always have to get the parent PID else it will keep spawning new processes) but it def feels like extra work when compared to this. Go manually delete the PID, lol. so straight forward, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On your terminal, please run this command

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

or if you have a specific version of postgres:

```
## version 11 for example
rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@11/postmaster.pid
```

Comment: just so you know, this worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the postgres server isn't running. Start the server by running

```
 sudo service postgresql start
```

Comment: Nope, but yesterday I could. `dartnyan@PC:~/Projects/shop$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is caused by an update of mac os, my configuration is Ruby 2.6.3 and rails 6.0.3.4 and I need PostgreSQL 12, verify that you have the correct version of PostgreSQL reinstall if you need and finally execute in your project:

gem uninstall pg

bundle install